# Parse HTML and get specific tag in IOS 8

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing

I tryed using HPPLE but it does not work with IOS 8, It points erros about the LibXML that I could not find a fix for..
I have an HTML which I inserted into an NSString, I want to get a specific tag text from that HTML code.
How can I do that in IOS 8?

I have added the 2 file:
libXML2
libXML2.2

and added the line "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" to the build settings,

I get the followin errors:

> /Users/giblix/Projects/FreeGal/FreeGal/XPathQuery.h:9:1: Unknown type
>   name 'NSArray'
>   /Users/giblix/Projects/FreeGal/FreeGal/XPathQuery.h:9:32: Unknown type
>   name 'NSData'

On the lines

```
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQueryWithEncoding(NSData *document, NSString *query,NSString *encoding);
```

in the file
XPathQuery.h

And a total of 18 errors of this type

Comment: Hpple works fine for me with libxml. What was the error? I link a library called `libxml2.2.dylib`

Comment: Using IOS 8?
I have add the LibXML2 and LibXML2.2 to the build phases and $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 to build settings, but I still get errors..

Comment: Yeah, in iOS 8. I'll assume you're testing on a device, correct?

Comment: I get build errors, Will post them now

Comment: Please edit your question with the error, don't paste it in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the top of `XPathQuery.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```